# Array search and unique value addition

Tags: c++, arrays

(Sorry if this is formatted terribly. I've never posted before.)

I've been working on a program for class for a few hours and I can't figure out what I need to do to my function to get it to do what I want. The end result should be that addUnique will add unique inputs to a list of its own.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void addUnique(int a[], int u[], int count, int &uCount);
void printInitial(int a[], int count);
void printUnique(int u[], int uCount);

int main() {
    //initial input
    int a[25];
    //unique input
    int u[25];
    //initial count
    int count = 0;
    //unique count
    int uCount = 0;
    //user input
    int input;

    cout << "Number Reader" << endl;
    cout << "Reads back the numbers you enter and tells you the unique entries" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 25 positive numbers. Enter '-1' to stop." << endl;
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
    do {
        cout << "Please enter a positive number: ";
        cin >> input;
        if (input != -1) {
            a[count++] = input;
            addUnique(a, u, count, uCount);
        }
    } while (input != -1 && count < 25);

    printInitial(a, count);
    printUnique(u, uCount);

    cout << "You entered " << count << " numbers, " << uCount << " unique." << endl;
    cout << "Have a nice day!" << endl;

}

void addUnique(int a[], int u[], int count, int &uCount) {
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        while (index < count) {
            if (u[uCount] != a[i]) {
                u[uCount++] = a[i];
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
}

void printInitial(int a[], int count) {
    int lastNumber = a[count - 1];
    cout << "The numbers you entered are: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << lastNumber << "." << endl;
}

void printUnique(int u[], int uCount) {
    int lastNumber = u[uCount - 1];
    cout << "The unique numbers are: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < uCount - 1; i++) {
        cout << u[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << lastNumber << "." << endl;
}
```

The problem is my addUnique function. I've written it before as a for loop that looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    if (u[i] != a[i]{
        u[i] = a[i]
        uCount++;
    }
}
```

I get why this doesn't work: u is an empty array so comparing a and u at the same spot will always result in the addition of the value at i to u. What I need, is for this function to scan all of a before deciding whether or no it is a unique value that should be added to u.

If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Code quality tip: comments like `//initial input` before variable declarations are a clear sign that you should give your variables better names. Why call it `a` when it could be `initial_input` (or only `input`)?

Comment: Great point. This is my first computer science course and I'm new to this, so I'm still learning what works best and how things should be. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: What is your algorithm? I mean, how do you want your code to approach this problem? If you were trying to find the unique elements with pencil and paper, how would you do it?

Comment: I want to have the inital array filled by the user (either partially or full). Then I want to look at the first number in that array and ask whether or no that number exists in unique. If it doesn't, I want to add it to the unique array, otherwise, I do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check for uniqueness is wrong...  As is your defintion of addUnique.

```
void addUnique(int value, int u[], int &uCount)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < uCount; i++){
    if (u[i] == value)
      return;   // already there, nothing to do.
  }
  u[uCount++] = value;
}
```